# Check if user can see Unicode symbol in JS

Tags: javascript, unicode

Is it possible to check if the user can see a Unicode symbol?
We have trouble with the ruble symbol on Ubuntu systems and Win XP ...
Code is U+20BD, ₽

On some systems it's not displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reliable way to check whether the user can see a particular character. The reason is that this mainly depends on the fonts installed in the user’s system and secondarily on the browser used. JavaScript cannot be used to scan through the fonts in the system and inspect their properties.

What you can do is to make a best effort at making the character show by using a downloadable font (web font, `@font-face` font), e.g. [PT Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Sans) as Google font:

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
* { font-family: PT Sans }
</style>
Рубль ₽
```